# Provide a way to create an OffsetAndMetdata with metadata when using Spring-Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

Kafka provides a way to define an *OffsetCommitCallback* in case of async commits on the consumer side. This callback gives an access to the offsets and metadata but when used with Spring Kafka, there is no way to populate these metadata.

See *KafkaMessageListenerContainer.ListenerConsumer#commitAsync*

When using pure Kafka, it's easy to set the metadata and access to the consumer information as the callback is directly added on the consumer but when used with Spring Kafka, the consumer is handled internally.

So, wouldn't it be possible to expose a new property on the ContainerProperties such as

```
public interface OffsetAndMetadataProvider {

   OffsetAndMetadata provide(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, long offset);
}
```

This optional provider may then be used in the listener container to create the OffsetAndMetadata object like

```
// would be called 6 times - see the internals of KafkaMessageListenerContainer
private OffsetAndMetadata createOffsetAndMetadata(long offset) {
   final OffsetAndMetadataProvider offsetAndMetadataProvider = containerProperties.getOffsetAndMetadataProvider();
   return offsetAndMetadataProvider == null
         ? new OffsetAndMetadata(offset)
         : offsetAndMetadataProvider.provide(consumer, offset)
}
```

Any other proposal to allow setting the metadata is more than welcome.
This issue is quite critical for my team and I.
I may also contribute on this request by dropping a pull request.

More details about the request can be provided.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for; the `OffsetAndMetadata` is populated by the consumer, not user code. You can add an `OffsetCommitCallback` to the `ContainerProperties`. Feel free to start a discussion on GitHub https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions and we can convert it to a new feature issue if we agree something is needed.

Comment: Let me rephrase, when using spring-kafka, the metadata field of the OffsetAndMetadata is always set to an empty string. In my use case, I would like to set it with the consumer group id but it's impossible as this object is built internally... Thanks for the quick reply. I will continue the discussion on GitHub.

Comment: @GaryRussell, as suggested, I started a discussion on Github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2169.